# Razor line continuations

Tags: razor

Is there anyway to make line continuations work in a razor view.

For example, the following code doesn't work

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Documents).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(x => x.FleetNumber).Named("Fleet No.");
    column.For(x => x.OrderNumber).Named("Order No.");
    column.For(x => x.DateCreatedForDisplay).Named("Created").SortColumnName("DateCreated");
})
.Empty("Sorry, no documents were found")
.Attributes(@class => "datagrid")
.Sort(Model.Query.SortOptions())
```

I have to put the last three lines onto one single line

```
@Html.Grid(Model.Documents).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(x => x.FleetNumber).Named("Fleet No.");
    column.For(x => x.OrderNumber).Named("Order No.");
    column.For(x => x.DateCreatedForDisplay).Named("Created").SortColumnName("DateCreated");
}).Empty("Sorry, no documents were found").Attributes(@class => "datagrid").Sort(Model.Query.SortOptions())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could denote that the whole thing is an expression like so:

```
@(Html.Grid(Model.Documents).Columns(column =>
{
    column.For(x => x.FleetNumber).Named("Fleet No.");
    column.For(x => x.OrderNumber).Named("Order No.");
    column.For(x => x.DateCreatedForDisplay).Named("Created").SortColumnName("DateCreated");
})
.Empty("Sorry, no documents were found")
.Attributes(@class => "datagrid")
.Sort(Model.Query.SortOptions()))
```

Note the additional parentheses.